# How to align parentheses with splitfrac?

Tags: brackets, fractions

I am looking to create a fraction in which the numerator is split into two lines using the \splitfrac command.  However, the denominator is short enough to not be split. All of this works well, except that the parentheses look really ugly as they are centered according to the horizontal line of the fraction instead of the entire fraction itself (for the MWE below it's doable but in the project I'm working on the formula is far more complex and the result looks horrible).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$$
\left(\frac{\splitfrac{a+b}{c+d}}{f}\right)
$$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I ensure that the parentheses are centered according to the entire fraction?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: (1) Never use `$$...$$` in latex, it does not comply to LaTeX configurations. (2) replace `\left( ... \right)` by `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}`

Comment: What's the reason for the parentheses?

Comment: Here there is no reason for parentheses, but in the actual formula I'm using it for in my project it is.

Comment: It worked with pmatrix, beautiful, thanks!

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `$$ ... $$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate displaymath mode. Use `\[ ... \]` instead. For a more in-depth discussion of this topic, please see the postings [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Answer (score 1):

There's no mathematical or typographic reason for enclosing the entire `\frac` expression in a pair of tall parentheses. If they're needed at all, they should enclose just the numerator term -- see the middle formula in the following screenshot. That said, this `\frac` formula really doesn't need parentheses at all -- see the formula on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\splitfrac{...}{...}' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\frac{\splitfrac{a+b}{c+d}}{f}\right) \quad
\frac{\left(\splitfrac{a+b}{c+d}\right)}{f} \quad
\frac{\splitfrac{a+b}{c+d}}{f}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree that it is not needed for my mwe. However, in my project I am using it for a logical expression that I find far too complicated to explain my issue here, in which it is really needed.

In any case, my problem was solved with pmatrix.