# Indent all equations in a document

Tags: math-mode, formatting, align, luatex

I'm currently writing my notes on a LaTex book, and I've decided to use this [template](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook). Additionally, I'm compiling with LuaTex since I have some Feynman diagrams with tikz.

I like to write my equations on my notebook starting from 2-3 cm from the left margin, independently on how long the equation is. There is a way to have all the equations aligned that way? To have something like this[image: this]

Edit: as suggested by @LuisTurcio, I've upladed `amsmath` and used  `fleqn`, and it works. The problem now is that to have the equations to look like that, I need to write them inside a `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, and I mostly use `$$..$$`. There is a way to have this option also for those equations?

Comment: Did you have tried loading `amsmath` with the option `fleqn`?

Comment: @LuisTurcio edited the question

Comment: `$$...$$` was a `PlainTeX` tags, please avoid to use it....

Comment: Please see the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) Anyway, if you want to create a displayed equation *without* an equation number in a LaTeX document, you should *not* be using the `equation` environment. Instead, you should be replacing `$$ ... $$` with `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: Ok I wrote only few equations so far, so not a big deal make the replacement, and now it works. There is also a way to set how much to indent the equations? Like 3 or 4 cm

Comment: Try with `\mathindent=4cm`

Comment: Perfect, works great!

Answer (score 1):

I've just combined the `commands` and made as suggestion...

```
1. $$...$$ was a PlainTeX tags, please avoid to use it.
2. if you want to create a displayed equation without an equation number in a LaTeX document, you should not be using the equation environment. Instead, you should be replacing $$ ... $$ with \[ ... \]
3. \mathindent= **cm is the tag which allowed you to indent the equations as your wish
```