# Messy block matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to typeset the following matrix

[image]

but I'm having trouble understanding the nicematrix package. I am trying to write it like this

```
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    \begin{pNiceArray}{cccc|ccc}
      \Block{2-2}<\Large>{\mathbf{S}}  & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{\mathbf{0}}  \\
      0 & A & -A & 0 \\
      \hline
      \Block{2-2}<\Large>{\mathbf{0}} && A & 0 & A
    \end{pNiceArray}
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
If you can give me any help I'll be grateful.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you place `S` in a block in your code? Do you want `S` to have an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: No, S is a fixed matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an `array`-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}     % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{multirow}  % for '\multirow' macro

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of the next instruction
\Large % '\Large' is a textmode command
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\left( \begin{array}{ l | c | c | c }
S & -A & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0} \\
\hline
\multirow{2.1}{*}{0} &  A & -A &  0 \\
\cline{2-4}
 & A & 0 & -A 
\end{array} \right)
\]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, is it wrong to enclose my matrix code in align as I did? Should I prefer to just use \[ \]? Also: is there a way to communicate the idea that the zero blocks are of course of different dimensions?

Comment: @Alex - I would not use an `align*` environment as there's nothing to align. I suppose you could use `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` if, for some reason, you're not comfortable with `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: @Alex  - Whoever reads your paper better be aware of the fact that the submatrices can be either square or non-square, depending on the situation. If there's any chance that readers don't "get" this, I wouldn't use the current notation. Instead, I'd write `0` twice in row 1 and once each at the start of rows 2 and 3.

Comment: @Alex - Please also familiarize yourself with the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) [shameless self-citation alert!]

Comment: Thanks for both of your suggestions. Would it be very hard to add something like a brace above the big zero block to specify the dimension?

Comment: @Alex - Assiuming `k` is the number of rows/columns of the square matrices, I'd change the upper-right zero matrix from `0` to `0_{\scriptscriptstyle k\times 2k}`; similarly, I'd change the lower-left zero matrix from `0` to `0_{\scriptscriptstyle 2k\times k}`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a possibility using `nicematrix`. The option `hvlines` creates the horizontal and vertical rules and respects the blocks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[hvlines]
S & -A & \Block{1-2}{0} &\\
\Block{2-1}{0} & A & -A & 0\\
& A & 0 & -A
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```