# Problem with writing a fraction expression

Tags: amsmath, fractions

I am trying to obtain an expression where I want to write the numerator in multiple aligned lines, and I need a denominator covering all of the numerator terms in a single line.
My equation is:

But I am trying to obtain its numerator in multiple lines as follows:

```
$$\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \lim_{s\rightarrow 1/2}E(r)=\frac{\Bigg[&\sqrt{1-r}\left(7-78 r+144 r^2\right) \operatorname{ArcTanh}\left[\frac{\sqrt{-1+3 r}}{\sqrt{3r}}\right]\\
    & +\sqrt{-3+9 r}\left(4(-6 \sqrt{1-r} r^{3 / 2}+\sqrt{(1-r) r})
    \\
    & +\left(-3+42 r-48 r^2\right) \operatorname{ArcTan}\left[\sqrt{\frac{1-r}{r}}\right]\right)
    \Bigg]}{144 \pi \sqrt{3-3 r r^{3 / 2}} \sqrt{-1+3 r}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
```

My code doesn't compile by using this, where is the problem? Guide and thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code *must* be generating an error message as you're encasing an `equation` environment in a pair of `$$` tokens. Please make your code compilable.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to run through a process like this before you post code: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . It avoids a flood of comments and will result in better answers sooner (though Mico did a great job once again). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First off, you have to remove the `$$` tokens that encase the `equation` environment. For an in-depth discussion of this subject, please see the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)
- Next, I suggest you load the `mathtools` package and employ its `\splitfrac` macro to create a three-line numerator. In the code shown below, observe that `\splitfrac` directives can be nested.

  If the line spacing employed by `\splitfrac` is too tight for your taste, I suggest replacing `\splitfrac` with `\splitdfrac`. (The letter `d` stands for `\displaystyle`.)
- I further recommend replacing the `\frac` terms in the numerator with inline-fraction expressions.
- And, because `\left` and `\right` sizing directives are not allowed to span line breaks, you must replace one of the inner `\left( ... \right)` constructs -- the one that would span lines 2 and 3 -- with explicit sizing directives. In the code below, I use `\bigl\{ ... \bigr\}`.

  More generally, don't treat the `\left` and `\right` sizing directives as crutches; instead, use them only when absolutely needed.
- As a final touch, I'd use a `^{\vphantom/}}` directive in the second square-root term in the denominator in order to equalize the heights of the adjacent square-root expressions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\splitfrac' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\ArcTan}{ArcTan}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ArcTanh}{ArcTanh}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{s\rightarrow 1/2}E(r)
  =\frac{
     \left( % encase entire numerator in tall parentheses
     \splitfrac{% start of first line
     \sqrt{1-r}(7 -78r +144r^2) 
     \ArcTanh[\sqrt{-1+3r}\big/\sqrt{3r}\,]}
      {\splitfrac{% start of second line
       {}+\sqrt{-3+9 r}\,\bigl\{4(-6\sqrt{1-r}\,r^{3/2}
       +\sqrt{(1-r) r}\,)} % end of second line
        {+(-3 +42r -48r^2) \ArcTan[(1-r)/r] \bigr\}
   } % end of inner \splitfrac
   } % end of outer \splitfrac
   \right) }% end of numerator
   {144 \pi \sqrt{3-3 r r^{3 / 2}} \sqrt{-1+3 r^{\vphantom{/}}}}
    % '^{\vphantom{/}}' serves to equalize the heights of the square-root symbols
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```