# Equations are not centered by default on a featured template listed by overleaf

Tags: equations, templates

I've been trying to work on [Basic Academic Journal Article Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/basic-academic-journal-article-template/hqyvzjmktytm) featured by Overleaf.

Although `$$ a + b = c$$` is centered, the following equations are not centered:

```
\[ a + b = c \]
\begin{equation*}
    a + b = c
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
    a + b = c
\end{equation}
```

[image: Three equations are not centered by default]

How do I revise the template to make all these equations centered by default?

Here is [my project](https://www.overleaf.com/4798771917hsfpnpdtykhp#0d6f32), which can be edited by anyone with the link. The original code in the project link is as follows.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,lineno]{olplainarticle}

\title{Example Article Title}

\author[1]{First Author}
\affil[1]{Address of first author}

\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{abstract}
  abstract 
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Mathematics}

$$ a + b = c $$

\[ a + b = c \]
\begin{equation*}
    a + b = c
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
    a + b = c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please don't hide your code behind a link: once you change it, this question becomes useless.  Trim your code down to the minimum that makes this happen, and then post that here.  (Also, you've given write access to the world.)  Templates are good for learning, but then you should start with a blank file and only add the things that you want.  Also, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks! I've revised as you suggest.

Comment: One should *not* use `$$` in LaTeX documents. For a longer discussion of this subject, please see the queries [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`,` \[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) The incompatibility of `$$` with the `fleqn` option is noted in the [most-upvoted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/5001) to the former query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your full document starts with this line:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,lineno]{olplainarticle}
```

The culprit is the document class option `fleqn` -- short for "flush-left equations". If you want equations to be centered rather than typeset flush-left, get rid of this option.

Comment: Or really, get rid of everything and start with an empty document and not a template that doesn't realize that `$$` is incompatible with `fleqn`.

Comment: @Teepeemm -- I was willing to give the OP the benefit of the doubt that there might be a valid reason for employing the `olplainarticle` [!] document class. :-)