# How to write this equation in LaTeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, equations

I would like to include the equations as the same as belows:

[image]

However, my code got me something very ugly:

```
\begin{equation}
Forecast Equation: \hat{y}_{t+1|t} = l_t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Smoothing Equation: l_t = \alpha y_t + (1-\alpha) l_{t-1},
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Does anyone can help me with this?

I would like to only give a number to an equation if I will refer to it later, then how to delete the number after the equation if I do not need it now?

The final question, how to align my equation to right, rather than centralise them?

Comment: Also, you might try \mathcal l, instead of just "L". This may result in a fancy script "L" as you posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this with variable spacing between the labels and the equations is to use an `alignat` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
   \text{Forecast Equation:}& \qquad & \hat{y}_{t+1 \vert t} &= l_t \nonumber \\
  \text{Smoothing Equation:}&        &                   l_t &= \alpha y_t + (1-\alpha) l_{t-1},
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

`\nonumber` would allow you to remove the numbering as needed (see [How do I turn off equation auto numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2597/5764)). Or, if the entire equation set should be unnumbered, use `alignat*`.

`alignat` will put the labels and the equations right next to one another. However, I inserted a `\qquad` to give a space of 2em between them. You can adjust this to suit your needs using `\hspace{<len>}`, where you specify `<len>`.

Comment: Thanks! It works well! So I do not need `\begin{equation}` for all my equations if I would like to align them to right?

Comment: @Jeannie -- in fact, it is very bad to put one `equation` right after another.  you should instead use one of the multi-line structures provided by `amsmath`.  see the documentation (`texdoc amsmath`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. Do you mean that I can keep with `equation` for one-line equation, and use other structure like `alignat` for multi-line equation?

Comment: @Jeannie: That's correct.