# How to not number an equation?

Tags: equations, numbering, unicode-math

I use `lualatex` with the package `unicode-math` instead of `amsmath`. How can I insert an equation without numbering? `\nonumber` option doesn't work with `unicode-math` package, and `\begin{equation*}` either.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\[` and `\]` should work...

Comment: Is there a conflict between `unicode-math` and `amsmath`?

Comment: There is not reason not to use amsmath together with unicode-math (but load amsmath first).

Comment: `unicode-math` is not a substitute for `amsmath`. The latter is not related in any way with math font selection. For technical reasons, it should be loaded before `unicode-math`.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it. The problem was that the amsmath package produced error and I thought it was incompatible with unicode-math. I introduced it in the first place and it already works for me.

Comment: If someone come across this searching for the title, refer to [How do I turn off equation auto numbering - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/how-do-i-turn-off-equation-auto-numbering) (`align → align*`).

Answer (score 9):

This works for me with `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    A
        &=B         \\
        &=BCD       \\
        &=B         
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
    A
        &=B         \label{eq:1}\\
        &=B         \notag\\
    A
        &=BCD       \label{eq:2}\\
        &=B         \label{eq:3}\tag{foo}
\end{align}

References: \eqref{eq:1}, \cref{eq:2}, \cref{eq:2,eq:1}, \cref{eq:2,eq:1,eq:3}.

\end{document}
```

As far as I know `\notag` and `\nonumber` are synonyms.

[image]

You might want to have a look on [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

Comment: The OP wants NO numbers...

Comment: @TeXnician: agreed and edited.

Comment: This answer should begin with an edited version of one of the two comments on the question: "
There is not reason not to use amsmath together with unicode-math (but load amsmath first)" -  Ulrike Fischer 
"unicode-math is not a substitute for amsmath. The latter is not related in any way with math font selection. For technical reasons, it should be loaded before unicode-math" - egreg

Answer (score -1):

Use the starred `equation*`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        E=mc^2
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```