# ! LaTeX Error: Environment equation* undefined

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to insert an equation without a number. I use the environment `equation*` (described in [How do I turn off equation auto numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/how-do-i-turn-off-equation-auto-numbering)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  a=b
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

When compiling I receive an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment equation* undefined.
```

The same problem is encountered when using the environment `align*` in place of `equation*`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Hi, but where is the \usepackage{amsmath}?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the standatd `\[ … \]`?

Comment: @Bernard, because I am not accustomed to the use of `\[ .. \]`. Maybe you could supply your answer for users like me.

Comment: @Viesturs `\[` is the standard form, any place that you have seen suggesting `equation*` must also have said to use `amsmath` to define it.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary.It's really  one of the basics of LaTeX. The situations when one has tto resort to`equation*` are much less frequent (an example would be with `empheq`).

Comment: @Bernard To the contrary, `amsmath` provides `equation*` so it's easy to switch from numbered to unnumbered equation and conversely.

Comment: @egreg: I very rarely use it, and anyway, a good editor also makes it easy to switch between equation and \[ … \] .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  a=b
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
 x&=y\\
  &=z
\end{align*}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]